# Querying from a database from different activities

Tags: java, android

I have created a database:

```
 public SQLiteDatabase playerDatabase;

  public void addPlayerToTheDatabase(PlayerList players){
        if(players == null){
            return;
        }

        FootySortItDatabase gameDatabase = new FootySortItDatabase(this);
        playerDatabase = gameDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
        for(PlayerDetails i : players.myPlayers){
            addNewPlayer(i);
        }


    }

    private long addNewPlayer(PlayerDetails player) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME, player.name);
        cv.put(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_PLAYER_NUMBER, player.number);

        return playerDatabase.insert(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }
```

And it works fine. No problem, I went through a debug and the database has the data as I want.

But I now want to query that same DB from another activity (a RecyclerView) but how do I pass the information from here to somewhere else or query that database from a different class in the same project?
So how do I make that DB accessiable to the whole project?

Comment: what is wrong in reapeating `FootySortItDatabase gameDatabase = new FootySortItDatabase(this);
        playerDatabase = gameDatabase.getWritableDatabase();` in others activity (or make instance of it some singleton)?

Comment: create object of that db class and use  it

Comment: please show whole code of your database class .

Answer (score 0):

**suppose this is your query inside db helper class**

```
public void RemoveCategoryPosts(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NEWS_CATEGORY);
        db.close();
    }
```

**then in any activity call like this**

```
Yourdbclassname db = new Yourdbclassname(this);

 db.open();

db.RemoveCategoryPosts();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity write

SQLiteDatabase db=databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor resVeh=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `tablename` ",null);